# Identify subversion of OS in Browserstack

Tags: browserstack

How can we identify the complete version(including subversion) of OS in browserstack?
eg. It shows iPhone 7 plus 10.3 only.
how would I know what is its subversion(i.e 10.3.2 or 10.3.3 etc)?
[browserstack phone select screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNMq1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below images for details:

[image: Real iOS device versions]

[image: iOS emulator versions]

Comment: What is IOS subversion for OS 10.3 in browserstack? i.e 10.3.1 or 10.3.2 or 10.3.3 etc for devices Iphone 7 and Iphone 7 plus.